# Apache Lucene FileNotFoundException on startup due to bad process stop

Tags: java, jboss, lucene

Answered

Client was not able to start the application after doing maintenance; either a deployment of a new WAR or a simple update of properties.  On start during the bean initialization, they would receive the following:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/app-directory/servers/app-workdir/lucene-index/_3gp1.si (No such file or directory)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:193) [lucene-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2 1586229 - rmuir - 2014-04-10 09:00:35]
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene46.Lucene46SegmentInfoReader.read(Lucene46SegmentInfoReader.java:49) [lucene-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2 1586229 - rmuir - 2014-04-10 09:00:35]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:340) [lucene-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2 1586229 - rmuir - 2014-04-10 09:00:35]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:404) [lucene-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2 1586229 - rmuir - 2014-04-10 09:00:35]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:843) [lucene-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2 1586229 - rmuir - 2014-04-10 09:00:35]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:694) [lucene-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2 1586229 - rmuir - 2014-04-10 09:00:35]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:400) [lucene-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2 1586229 - rmuir - 2014-04-10 09:00:35]
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:746) [lucene-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2 1586229 - rmuir - 2014-04-10 09:00:35]
at proprietary class
at proprietary class
... 50 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Determined root cause was the way the client developed their application stop shell script, which was issuing a SIGKILL/"kill -9" which terminated the application server while Lucene was in the middle of updating the index.

Instead, using SIGTERM/"kill -15" to signal the application is how we were doing it internally, and how we are recommending the client perform the stop. This should allow Lucene to finish any processes in flight and not corrupt the index.

The thing that led us to that was the fact the stopping messages did not exist in the server.log

```
09:10:41,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment sqljdbc4.jar (runtime-name: sqljdbc4.jar) in 18998ms
09:10:41,525 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ojdbc6.jar (runtime-name: ojdbc6.jar) in 19169ms
```